# How to query Athena string to date in hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Hi I have created following schema in AWS Athena to read csv file from AWS S3

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS axlargetable.mine (
  createdate string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   ) 
LOCATION 's3://ax-large-table/test/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

"createdate" column holding following values

```
7/01/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/03/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/04/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/05/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/06/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/31/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/31/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/31/2017 5:40:05 PM
7/31/2017 5:40:05 PM
```

How can I query "createdate" column value as date format?  sample query like

```
Select * from axlargetable.mine 
where createdate between '7/03/2017' and '7/31/2017'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid the OpenCSVSerDe does not support parsing `date` types with some non-ISO formatting. The only way you can circumvent this behavior is, that you translate the string into a date within your query.

In that case, you would need to use the `parse_date` function.

```
select * from axlargetable.mine
where date_parse(createdate, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') 
          between DATE'2017-03-07' and DATE'2017-07-31';
```

Comment: Hi Jens Thank yo for your answer and I am getting value but I am little bit confused about the date structure here is that '2017-03-07' 'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'yyyy-dd-mm',

Comment: Sorry I got the answer, Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yes, copy/paste error, sorry. It should be 2017-07-03 meaning 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Comment: Can I ask you another favour, If I would like to include time what would be the code. Thanks

Comment: If you stick with ISO-format, you can just use the TIMESTAMP type, otherwise use the parse_date again. "between TIMESTAMP'2017-07-03 18:03:02' and date_parse('7/06/2017 5:40:08 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')"